# Retrieve GPS location across multiple tabs for Map activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-maps, android-location, android-mapview

I would like my app to start attempting locate the users location on launch, the map is not the first tab presented to user, and when the user navigates away from the map tab the location seeking stops.

I'd like the map tab (or every activity in the tab) to be searching for the users location, as  its quite central to the users interaction with the app. I'm not sure if using a Thread is the answer, nor do I have any idea how I would go about doing this. Is there recommended way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you mean by tab as I cannot visualise the structure of your whole application

However, if you want the phone to be getting GPS updates, you only need to call

```
LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(); //to start e.g. in onResume()
LocationManager.removeUpdates();          //in onPause()
```

As I see it, you seem to be creating a Google Map 'wholesale' just for the sake of the GPS coordinates. If that is the case, you are probably better off learning and using the LocationManager API.

Comment: So we have a three tab layout, one of which we have called map and currently thats the only place within the app that the LocationManager is called and the tab has to be the active one for this to happen.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, from my experience, maps are not good with tabs, unless you do customized tabs..

If you still want to use tabs, I recommend that you create a background service connected with the not initial tab, but you start this service in the initial tab, but you do a mechanism that the service wont operate unless the other tab is focused.

Good luck